# Python numpy nan to num error

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have a 2D array which looks something as:

```
Load
array([[768.632379, nan],
       [851.494329, nan],
       [947.736291, nan],
       [668.199965, nan],
       [843.410303, nan],
       [1022.489209, nan]], dtype=object)

type(Load)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

When I try:

```
numpy.nan_to_num(Load[:,1])
```

it generates:

```
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object)
```

when I try:

```
np.nan_to_num(Load)
array([[768.632379, nan],
       [851.494329, nan],
       [947.736291, nan],
       [668.199965, nan],
       [837.19925, nan],
       [1022.489209, nan], dtype=object)
```

I want to convert all the nan in the second column of Load array to 0.

Also:

```
type(Load[0,1])
<type 'float'>
```

Edit: I am reading data from a csv file using pandas so it creates objects there.

Comment: Why do you have an array of object dtype?

Comment: Your data has `dtype=object`, you need to convert it to `double`.  `numpy.nan_to_num(Load[:, 1].astype('d'))` works.